# Windows Hello isn't working on laptop with one user

Tags: windows-10, biometrics, windows-hello

I've set up a GPO to enable windows hello, and have been successful in getting it to work however something seems to disable it for some users on some laptops.. for example

Set up new HP Elitebook x360
Logged in with normal test user part of GPO - windows hello enabled
Logged in with user who I was setting laptop up for - options greyed out

Added a different laptop to the GPO and logged into her account - windows hello enabled

So the GPO works, but something on her user on this PC is disabling it?

Any ideas?

Comment: So this is a domain environment?

Comment: yes domain, both accounts and laptops tested on are domain joined

Comment: Unfortunately domain systems are off topic here. Nothing we can do, only your IT support can do anything.

Comment: I am the IT support, at a loss as to why it works with one account and not the other on the same laptop, and the account that doesnt work, works on another laptop. Where can I go to be ontopic? thanks

Comment: Ben, ServerFault.

Comment: Ben, consider deleting that profile entirely and seeing if a new user profile allows the use of the account with the Hello biometrics or whatever you are using. You'll definitely want to move over to https://serverfault.com and open the question on that sister community for server related environment things I think. But rebuilding the Windows account user profile is simply enough to do since you are the IT support this should be a standard thing in your world—was for me when I provided PC support for end-user and Windows OSes.